# append a new div with slide effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, slide

this is an example of my code :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Effects - Effect demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="toggler">
  <a href="#" id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</a>
    <div id="add">
    </div>  
    <div id="oldli" class="newclass">
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery (test.js):

```
$(function() {
    // run the currently selected effect
    function runEffect() {
      // get effect type from
      var selectedEffect = 'slide';

      // most effect types need no options passed by default
      var options = {};

      // run the effect

      var temp = '<div class=""><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div></div>'
    $(temp).insertAfter('div#add').effect({effect:'slide',direction:'up',queue:false});

    };

    // callback function to bring a hidden box back
    function callback() {

    };

    // set effect from select menu value
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      runEffect();
      return false;
    });
  });
```

for now when you press run effect the new div is add with slide effect but the old data is just appears at his new location after the insert
i want the old data to be pushed down with the same slide effect and to be synchronized with the slide effect of the new inserted data  and to continue doing that with every new data that is inserted

Comment: You have closing `ul` and `div` tags without opening the respective tags.

Comment: it was a copy paste mistake

Answer (score 0):

You should add it as a hidden `div` and you should use `blind` effect instead of `slide`. 
Like this:

JS

```
var temp = '<div class="newli"><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div></div>';
function runEffect() {
      $(temp).insertAfter('#add').show("blind", {
        direction: "up"
    }, 1000);
};
```

CSS

```
.newli {
    display: none;
}
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/DCWWR/

Comment: i found the solution by combing the 2 like this     $(temp).insertAfter('div#add').show("blind", {
        direction: "up",
  queue:false,speed:'slow'
    }).effect({effect:'slide',direction:'up',queue:false,speed:'slow'});